# How to use an 'if' loop multiple times in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def hit():
    global hitsum
    hitsum = 0
    v=random.choice(cards)
    c=random.choice(suits)
    if v=="Ace":
        hitsum=hitsum+1
        print "You were dealt","a",v,"of",c
    elif v=="Jack":
        hitsum=hitsum+11
        print "You were dealt","a",v,"of",c
    elif v=="Queen":
        hitsum=hitsum+12
        print "You were dealt","a",v,"of",c
    elif v=="King":
        hitsum=hitsum+13
        print "You were dealt","a",v,"of",c
    else:
        hitsum=hitsum+v
        print "You were dealt","a",v,"of",c

computer()

choice=raw_input("Would you like to hit or stay? ")
if choice=="hit":
    hit()
    totalsum = hitsum + usersum
    print "Your total is", totalsum

elif choice=="stay":
    totalsum=usersum

else:
    print "Invalid request"
```

This code is an excerpt from my blackjack game. I made a user defined function for randomly generating a card whenever someone asks for a hit. However this only works for one choice. If i choose hit once, I don't get an option to choose it again. how do i rectify that?

Comment: you need a while loop or  a for loop using range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
choice=raw_input("Would you like to hit or stay? ")
while choice=="hit":
    hit()
    totalsum = hitsum + usersum
    print "Your total is", totalsum
    choice=raw_input("Would you like to hit or stay? ")
```

I would strongly recommend changing how `hit` and `hitsum` are handled.  Instead of making it global, why not return it?  So at the end of `hit`, you would have

```
return hitsum
```

So then in the call you could do

```
totalsum = usersum + hit()
```

I see a few other issues here as well.  The next time through your `choice==hit` loop, usersum will be back to whatever it used to be.  I don't think that's what you want.  Surely you want to increase `usersum` by `hitsum`.  In that case, replace the `totalsum = ...` by

```
usersum += hit()
```

Finally, in your `hit` function, why define `hitsum=0` at the beginning?

Comment: note - just noticed I had a bug in my initial code snippet.  I just corrected it.  So if you grabbed an earlier version, you want to update it.

Comment: Thanks Joel! Went through all your suggestions and it really helped me with my problems.